# How do I implement a static variable in viewmodel in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a variable in App.cs:

```
  public static string StatusText = "";
```

And ViewModel like this:

```
     public string StatusText
     {
        get { return App.StatusText; }
        set
        {
            if (value == App.StatusText) return;
            App.StatusText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }
```

In the view I have a label like this:

```
<Label x:Name="TxtReport" Text="{Binding StatusText}" />
```

My intent is to have some sort of handle from the View to change StatusText programmatically so any Label bound to it will automatically update.
Also I don't want to assign TxtReport.Text directly because I can only do this safely from the main thread (or use BeginInvokeOnMainThread).
What's the best approach? I have seen suggestions of using MessagingCenter. Is this the only way?

Comment: No, there are countless ways. Best way is always opinion based and that kind of questions are off-topic here on SO. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Sorry, I should had worded this differently. I just would like to know how to implement it without using MessagingCenter

Comment: Ok, but why do you want not to use MessagingCenter? You need some kind of notification, so all of the possible solutions are all more or less similar but with different flavor :o)

Comment: You can have a look at [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net)